# How to define affine/projective varieties over fields which are not algebraically closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

In general, you come across affine and projective varieties as defined over algebraically closed fields, such as in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, who defines

- an algebraic variety as an irreducible algebraic subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$, endowed with the induced topology.
- a projective variety as an irreducible algebraic subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$, endowed with the induced topology.

**My questions:**

- Where exactly do I need that the field is algebraically closed for this definition (or maybe for other definitions necessary for this one)?
- How would I need to alter these definitions in case of a non-algebraically closed field? 
  (I was thinking that it has to do sth with the definition of an algebraic set based on this post [Affine variety over a field which is not algebraically closed can be written as the zero set of a single polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642593/affine-variety-over-a-field-which-is-not-algebraically-closed-can-be-written-as) , i.e I do not have whole set of polynomials such that my variety equals the vanishing locus over them, but only one polynomial?)

Thank you!

Comment: I suppose the problem is that in the non-algebraically closed field, there is no more a one-to-one correspondence between points in varieties and maximal ideals in $k$-algebras. Hilbert's Nullstellensatz tells us that in the alg. closed field, a point $(a,b,c)$ in a variety corresponds to the maximal ideal $(x-a,y-b,c-z)$. However, for example in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, this does not happen. To be specific, there is no point associated with the maximal ideal $(x^2+1)$.

Comment: And also, I am not quite sure about this, but since every field $k$ has an algebraic closure $\bar{k}$, so polynomials that generates the ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ can be viewed as polynomials of $\bar{k}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and if we know all about $\bar{k}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then maybe we automatically get to know all about $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. At least I think every algebraic set in $k^n$ can be viewed as the intersection of an algebraic set in $\bar{k}^n$ and $k^n \subset \bar{k}^n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical shift that happens when moving to fields which aren't algebraically closed (or more general rings) is that one redefines what $\Bbb A^n_R$ and $\Bbb P^n_R$ are for the the ring $R$. Instead of declaring that $\Bbb A^n_R$ is the set $R^n$ with a funny topology, one says that $\Bbb A^n_R = \operatorname{Spec} R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, and similarly, instead of regarding $\Bbb P^n_R$ as "lines through the origin in $R^{n+1}$", we think of it instead as lines through the origin in $\Bbb A^{n+1}_R = \operatorname{Spec} R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ (also known as $\operatorname{Proj} R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$). Sometimes you'll also see people drop the "irreducible" adjective - the general formulation is that an affine (resp. projective) variety is a closed subscheme of $\Bbb A^n$ (resp. $\Bbb P^n$) satisfying some adjectives, which often vary from author to author.

This redefinition gives you many more points in $\Bbb A^n_K$ if $K$ is not an algebraically closed field - for any $K'$ a Galois extension of $K$, we get a point for every Galois orbit in $K'$. Having access to these points means the sorts of shenanigans you're attempting to pull off in the linked question don't work - every polynomial's zero set has the correct dimension, etc.